# Выборка данных из связных таблиц

Tags: sql, sqlite, запрос

Есть схема бд, в этой схеме есть таблицы, которые связываются через таблицу(Если есть вариант получше - в студию).
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Решил выполнить запрос на выборку:
Выбрать departurePoint, arrivalPoint, name(**bus**), price(**price**), name(**stop**)(все остановки, где стает автобус), time(**time**)(один маршрут с начальной точки в конечную в день ходит 20 раз и нужно выбрать что бы все эти времена выводились).

Начал писать сам запрос

```
SELECT TIME, nameBus, namePrice FROM (TIME JOIN time_flight USING (_id_time)) JOIN flight USING (_id_flight)
INNER JOIN busеs AS b ON b._id = flight.bus
INNER JOIN price AS p ON p._id = flight.price
WHERE _id_flight = 1
```

И он выводит, в принципе, то что мне нужно, только кроме этого мне еще нужно что бы выводились остановки, через какие этот автобус проходит

Вот сама бд и ее данные:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Таблица **Stop**:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Таблица **Ttime**:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Таблица **Flight**:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Таблица **StopFlight**:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Таблица **TimeFlight**:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте выполнить такой запрос,без использования Join:

```
SELECT TIME,
       nameBus,
       namePrice,
       stopName
  FROM flight,
       time_flight,
       time,
       bus,
       price,
       stop_flight,
       stop
 WHERE     time.id = time_flight.id_time
       AND time_flight.id_flight = flight.id
       AND flight.id = stop_flight.id_flight
       AND stop_flight.id_stop = stop=id 
       and flight.bus=dus.id 
       and flight.price=price.id 
       and _id_flight = 1
```

Comment: Оно выводит не то что мне нужно. Мой запрос, что приведен в примере, выводит мне для первого рейса(от 1 остановки до 2) времена только этого рейса(получается 6 записей). В вашем случае он мне выводит 12 записей, и каждая запись повторяется, отличается только то, что название остановок разные, а время для одного рейса(в одну сторону) и другого рейса(в обратную сторону) одинаковое(для того и другого, например, 6:30, хотя он в 6:30 выезжает из одной остановки, а с другой уже через 40 минут, к примеру)